# Why JSON.stringify() don't work correctly

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

I'm actually creating a JSON file with nodejs but when i use the JSON.stringify.
My Json Object work correctly when i print it :

[My code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8E79s.png)

But when i stringify my json object i get that :

[What i receive when i print my json object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6eJd7.png)

A big part of my json information don't want to be save i don't know why
Here's the code :

[What i receive when i print my stringified json object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QpjKr.png)

Comment: I reverse my first and last link sorry ^^'

Comment: Code should be posted **here** as text, not as links to images.

Comment: Sorry i rarely post a question on stackoverflow so i don't know how it work exactly

Comment: Also in your code the "object" is a syntax error.

Comment: There's [ample documentation of how to ask good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), but it doesn't do any good if you don't read it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are attempting to use a 'sparse array' to store your data. Arrays do not have a clear way to be instantiated with elements at a specified index.

An object (or a Map) would suit your requirements better. To use an object, I modified your 'accounts' initation code that was commented:

```
// replace this:
dataObj["accounts"] = [];
// with this:
dataObj["accounts"] = {};
```

The other code you are using (e.g. accessing elements using the square brackets) will work the same. You should probably make the same adjustments to the other arrays you are using.

Sparse arrays can get ugly in some notations if you have large blank spaces (which your UUID methodology would certainly have). An object or a Map will not suffer that shortcoming.

An example of similar code, using objects instead of arrays:

```
let dataObj = {};
dataObj["accounts"] = {};
let uuid = 'abcdefghij12344';
dataObj["accounts"][uuid] = {}
dataObj["accounts"][uuid]['active'] = true;
dataObj["accounts"][uuid]['someotherval'] = true;
 
console.log(dataObj);
//outputs:

{ accounts: { abcdefghij12344: { active: true, someotherval: true } } }

let stringified = JSON.stringify(dataObj);
console.log(stringified);

// Outputs:
{"accounts":{"abcdefghij12344":{"active":true,"someotherval":true}}}

let parsed = JSON.parse(stringified);
console.log(parsed);

//Outputs:
{ accounts: { abcdefghij12344: { active: true, someotherval: true } } }
```